# Book about a man becoming a saint for humanity

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

A child is sent to a prison mining colony on the belt. There is a general at the prison and promotes the child to admiral. The child and general escape and travel the Sol system as a traveling performance. As time goes on more people join the kid, now a man.

The Earth government is under the UN and the police force is called the Peacekeepers. But the government is corrupt and the admiral fight the government with the people that follow him and they call him saint because of how good he is.

The saint wins a lot of battles against the UN and the evil leader of the UN dies from assassination from within; a new leader takes command and offers peace with the saint but that his group must surrender and then they would be pardoned, so the saint does.

Comment: does anyone know if the author is going to wright more of this universe. I cant find anything online. it seems the author is a hermit from the internet. only found 1 photo of him and that's what is on the books. no other info on him.

Comment: @AveryGeneEscarzega It sounds like there's not much known about the author, and he/she has only written 5 books: http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/etheridge_rutledge

Comment: from what ive seen the name used is a cover name. I was wondering if the writing seems familiar. what other writer has similar writing. the duelist books have a unique writing to them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the title.

the First Duelist by Rutledge Etheridge